# Tratamiento de las contraseñas en el script

Tags: python, hashmap

Estoy trabajando en un script que se conecta a una API y que por lo tanto tiene un usuario y contraseña exclusivo.

Pensando como puedo hacer para que mis datos no estén en el propio código, me he encontrado desde gente que los externaliza en un JSON, hasta gente que aplica encriptación y *hashing*. Concretamente, el método que leo parece el más seguro es el de *hashing* (quizás me equivoco). Por lo tanto es el que he intentado implementar.

Para este objetivo veo que se emplea la librería `passlib`, concretamente, `CryptContext`:

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
```

Y que de manera muy sencilla se puede generar el mapa,

```
# create CryptContext object
context = CryptContext(
        schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
        default="pbkdf2_sha256",
        pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
)
# hash password
hashed_password = context.hash("test_password")
# Verify correct work
print(context.verify("test_password", hashed_password))
```

Pero la pregunta es, que hago ahora con esto? No termino de comprender cual es el siguiente paso una vez has generado el *hash*. ¿Guardo este *hash* en un json?

La idea sería poder quitar el usuario y contraseña de mi clase `appAPI` y hacer el proceso más seguro.

```
class appAPI:
    def __init__(self):
      self.headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
      self.url = 'https://xxx.eee.com:33942/api/external/'


    def login(self): para identificarse en la API.
        params = {'username': 'USER_AAA', 'password': 'PASS_BBB'}
        response = requests.post(self.url+'login', data=json.dumps(params), 
                                 headers=self.headers, verify=False)
        response = json.loads(response.text)
        code = response.get('status').get('code')
        ...
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El hash se guarda en una BD tu no tienes que guardar el hash *localmente*, tu trabajo es generar el hash y luego comprobar que ese coincida con alguno de tu BD

Comment: Entonces que diferencia hay entre hacer eso y guardar directamente la contraseña? Debe ser una obviedad pero no lo veo...

Comment: El hash es un método de encriotacion, si tu BD es vulnerada no podrán acceder directamente a las contraseñas sino al hash  el cual es único para cada cadena

Comment: Un hash `sha256` es "irreversible", por lo que si hasheas tus credenciales e intentas usar ese hash para autenticarte con la API se te denegará el acceso pues no serán correctas (la API espera algo como `mi password` pero recibe el hash `abcde2341` (proveniente de  `hash('mi password')`)). Si quieres proteger esas credenciales yo diría que las pongas en un  `.env` y si quieres estar más seguro, encriptes ese archivo (simétrica o asimétricamente), lo desencriptes en el código y envies tus credenciales de autenticación ya desencriptadas.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre los JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

Comment: Por lo poco que sé, crear y almacenar al hash, lo hace quien debe verificar la contraseña, o sea, el servidor, no el cliente. Dicho de otra manera, esa API te está pidiendo una contraseña, si le mandas otra cosa no va a funcionar. Si lo que pretendes es guardar esa contraseña en el cliente... puedes cifrarla... pero a la hora de pasarla a la API debes volver a descifrarla, así que siempre será inseguro ya que el cliente debe disponer de la información para descifrarlo.

Comment: creo que hay un poco de confusión, pues el archivo `.env` se utiliza para guardar datos sensibles de tu aplicación (como una conexión a tu BD, puerto, etc). En la pregunta se plantea el hecho de guardar una contraseña (de un usuario x) en algún lugar (Base de datos) No tiene ningún sentido guardar una contraseña de un usuario en un archivo de configuración, tampoco tiene mucho sentido encriptar la info de ese archivo, pues sus datos están en las variables de entorno del sistema.

Answer (score 4):

## Hashing

El *hashing* es un proceso de encriptación, el cual recibe una cadena de longitud variable y **siempre** devuelve una cadena de una longitud fija (224, 256, 384 y 512 bits) la longitud depende del algoritmo elegido. Todas las funciones de hash son determinísticas, es decir, mientras que su input no varíe, el resultado será el mismo. Muchos de estos algoritmos están *diseñados* de forma unidireccional, lo que quiere decir que solo puedes obtener el valor final, es muy difícil obtener el valor original. Esta dificultad es determinada por la longitud de la cadena resultante (bytes) y por eso algoritmos como `md5` han sido rotos.

## Funcionamiento

Las funciones de hash utilizan distintos procedimiento y algoritmos para hacer la
*encriptación* de una cadena, se realizan distintas operaciones matemáticas. El cambio más minimo en una cadena conlleva a un resultado distinto, no es lo mismo *hashear* `Hola` que `hola` (sea cual sea el algoritmo) esto dará resultados completamente distintos y sin similitud aparente.

Los *hash* son muy usados en temas de encriptación y cosas que requieran que los datos estén seguros, como por ejemplo, contraseñas, criptomonedas, protección de archivos, etc. En tu caso, lo que tu requieres es *cifrar* una contraseña con el algoritmo `sha256` *Secure Hash Algorithms* cuyo resultado será una cadena de 256 bytes.

Al momento que un usuario se registre en tu sitio o utilice tu *endpoint* tendrás que cifrar la contraseña (texto plano) que haya puesto, una vez teniendo esa contraseña *hasheada* tendrás que almacenarla en una BD o donde quieras. Aquí no importa mucho donde la guarde ya que si alguien accede a las contraseñas no le servirá de nada pues está encriptada y no la puede usar. Pero aun así es recomendable guardarlas en un lugar seguro, pues nunca sabes cuando el algoritmo será roto.

Ahora cuando el usuario quera acceder nuevamente a tu sitio web (o utilizar el otro endpoint) solo tenemos que volver a *hashear* la contraseña (texto plano) y al tener el resultado del *hash* comprobamos esa contraseña en la BD (o donde sea que la tengas). Esto es muy sencillo gracias al principio antes mencionado (*los hash son determinísticas*) donde el resultado de una cadena, que no sea modificada, siempre será el mismo.

##### según tu ejemplo

No he trabajo con BD en python (ORM) por lo que no puedo dar un ejemplo concreto. Pero haré mi mayor esfuerzo.
**para crear al usuario**

```py
# create CryptContext object
context = CryptContext(
        schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
        default="pbkdf2_sha256",
        pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
)
# hash password
hashed_password = context.hash("test_password") #contraseña encriptada

#guardas en tu BD
DB.insert(hashed_password)
```

**validar al usuario**

```py
context = CryptContext(
        schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
        default="pbkdf2_sha256",
        pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
)
usuario = "Christian"

result = DB.find(user == usuario)
if result:
    context.verify("test_password", hashed_password)
```

Tanto el usuario como la contraseña (texto plano) lo puedes obtener mediante un `input` o alguna petición `post`. Lo siento por no poder dar un ejemplo claro y preciso, pero creo que la lógica se entiende.

Comment: Muy interesante y muy buena la explicación. Mi preocupación venía en DONDE lo guardo y realmente creo entender que en realidad me he de preocupar en COMO lo guardo. Aplicando hashing, no queda constancia de la contraseña cómo tal y además el valor que queda almacenado en la bbdd no es aquel que se debe introducir en el formulario de acceso por lo tanto aunque no imposible, dificulta el acceder al destino final.

Comment: Exacto, aunque también juega un papel importante el cliente y el servidor, si todo lo haces en el cliente existe un menor riesgo, pero si lo haces en el servidor, el cliente tendrá que cifrar la contraseña para mandarla al servidor, ya que sería muy inseguro mandar ala contraseña (texto plano) al servidor

Answer (score 3):

Lo convencional es almacenar credenciales encriptadas simetricamente en un archivo de configuración protegido (p. ej. solo accesible al súper usuario) o en una base de datos.
Aquí el ejemplo de encripción simétrica (reversible) obtenido de https://gist.github.com/syedrakib/d71c463fc61852b8d366:

```
# Basado en https://pythonprogramming.net/encryption-and-decryption-in-python-code-example-with-explanation/
# Documentación PyCrypto https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64, os

def generar_clave_privada_cifrado_AES():    
    # La longitud de clave AES debe ser de 16, 24 o 32 bytes
    longitud_clave_AES = 16 # usar valor más grande en producción   
    # generar una clave secreta aleatoria con la longitud seleccionada  
    # esta clave secreta será usada para crear el cifrado AES para encripción/desencripción
    clave_secreta = os.urandom(longitud_clave_AES)  
    # codificar la clave secreta a string binario en base 64, para almacenarla de forma segura en una base de datos o archivo
    clave_secreta_codificada = base64.b64encode(clave_secreta)
    return clave_secreta_codificada

def encriptar_mensaje(mensaje_privado, clave_secreta_codificada, caracter_relleno): 
    # decodificar la clave secreta
    clave_secreta = base64.b64decode(clave_secreta_codificada)  
    # usar la clave decodificada para crear un cifrado AES
    cipher = AES.new(clave_secreta)
    # rellenar el mensaje_privado   
    # debido a que la encripción AES requiere que la longitud del mensaje sea múltiplo de 16
    mensaje_privado_rellenado = mensaje_privado + (caracter_relleno * ((16-len(mensaje_privado)) % 16)) 
    # usar cipher para encriptar el mensaje rellenado
    mensaje_encriptado = cipher.encrypt(mensaje_privado_rellenado)
    # codificar en base 64 el mensaje encriptado para almacenarlo de forma segura en una base de datos o archivo
    mensaje_encriptado_codificado = base64.b64encode(mensaje_encriptado)    
    # devolver el mensaje encriptado y codificado
    return mensaje_encriptado_codificado

def desencriptar_mensaje(mensaje_encriptado_codificado, clave_secreta_codificada, caracter_relleno):    
    # decodificar el mensaje encriptado y la clave secreta
    clave_secreta = base64.b64decode(clave_secreta_codificada)
    mensaje_encriptado = base64.b64decode(mensaje_encriptado_codificado)    
    # usar la clave secreta decodificada para crear un objeto cipher AES
    cipher = AES.new(clave_secreta) 
    # usar el objeto cipher para desencriptar el mensaje
    mensaje_desencriptado = cipher.decrypt(mensaje_encriptado)    
    mensaje_desencriptado = mensaje_desencriptado.decode('utf-8')           
    # quitar caracter de relleno
    mensaje_privado_sin_relleno = mensaje_desencriptado.rstrip(caracter_relleno)    
    # devolver el mensaje privado original
    return mensaje_privado_sin_relleno


mensaje_privado = "Mensaje privado"
caracter_relleno = "{"

clave_secreta = generar_clave_privada_cifrado_AES()
mensaje_encriptado = encriptar_mensaje(mensaje_privado, clave_secreta, caracter_relleno)
mensaje_desencriptado = desencriptar_mensaje(mensaje_encriptado, clave_secreta, caracter_relleno)

print ("           Clave privada: %s longitud: (%d)" % (clave_secreta, len(clave_secreta)))
print ("   Credencial encriptada: %s longitud: (%d)" % (mensaje_encriptado, len(mensaje_encriptado)))
print ("Credencial desencriptada: %s longitud: (%d)" % (mensaje_desencriptado, len(mensaje_desencriptado)))
```

También es posible almacenar credenciales en variables de ambiente del S.O. pero hay que tener en cuenta que se puedan perder en un reinicio (sin embargo no uses nombres de variables obvios para no vulnerar la seguridad).

```
import os

credencial_api= os.environ['CREDENCIAL_API']
```

Igualmente podrías usar el ejemplo anterior para encriptar el valor antes de almacenarlo en la variable de ambiente.